# Unspecified Error - 80004005

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I am getting error

```
Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'  
Unspecified error
```

in ASP code on line while open database connection. Sometime it works sometimes not. Not getting any solutions.

Comment: Can you paste your connection logic? (I.e., are you opening multiple connections? Referencing one connection each time? )

Comment: What Web Server are you running?  And can you post a code snippet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP Weird Unspecified Error - 80004005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840762/asp-weird-unspecified-error-80004005)

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306269

http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/80004005-errors.html

Comment: The second link seems to be broken. Could you include the gist in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving permissions to everyone on both the directory the .mdb is in, and the .mdb itself.

Comment: But without ne changes sometime it works. So its not permission as well as scripting problem.

Comment: Actually, that may be an erroneous conclusion.  If the lock file is the file that's actually causing problems, then you would expect intermittent success / failures.  It could be picking up the permissions of the parent directory when created, and locked for the next web-request.