# Connection to access database fails after authentication

Tags: authentication, windows-7, asp-classic, oledbconnection

Using classic ASP on Windows 7pro or Windows 8.1pro, I connect to a Microsoft Access 2003 database with the connection string "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=D:\INetPub\KN2014\Databases".

This works fine **until** I call for user authentication with the code:

```vb
sAccount=Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")'NT challenge
if sAccount="" then 
    Response.Status="401 Unauthorized"
    Response.End
end if
```

The authentication is forced on a **different** page. If I do this in the same window and then return to the page which connects to the database a 80004005: Unspecified error occurs. Only resolution is to close the window and reopen it. If I manually open a second window (same sessionID!) I get the same problem in the second window. The first keeps working fine, even after a refresh.

I've tried to open that second window with program code, but then I get the error in the first window also.

Searching this site, I have done the trick granting read access on sysWOW64/inetsrv. Also: If I do a clean install for Windows 7, it works fine for a while than "Something happens" (maybe installing VS of Office) and the old problem occurs again. Tricks like using basic authentication, using Kerberos or changing the order of authentication protocols seem to have no effect.

I'm an "old school" developer. I hope someone can help me by providing the most simple classic ASP code to do authenticate using windows verification and read/write access to a Microsoft access db.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with that code as that just returns a 401 status to the browser if it's using anonymous authentication to the asp page. Your problem is you open the connection exclusively to the database not closing it again and closing the browser does not kill a session immediately so you'll end up with a database lock. See [80004005 Errors](http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/80004005-errors.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP Weird Unspecified Error - 80004005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840762/asp-weird-unspecified-error-80004005)

Answer (score 1):

With Access you need to make sure that your database working in multi-user mode (available on 2010 and later) and you need to detect when user leave your page to close connection to Access upon exiting/closing your site/page.
That is a curse of Access since earliest versions of it.

Or make sure that you open database without locks. IN SQL server that could be achived by executing following upon opening your SQl statement:

```
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

But I am not sure if this even possible in Access, better option just to switch to SQL Express.